# How to update cell value of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview binds the datasource from a dataview, but this dataview doesn't contain all value I need for datagridview.
So, I would like to update some cell value from other table.
But It doesn't work...
this is my code

```
private DataView _dvMarket;
public void InitData(DataView dvMarket)
{
    _dvMarket = dvMarket;
    dgvMarket.DataSource = null;
    dgvMarket.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvMarket.DataSource = _dvMarket;
    
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMarket.Rows)
    {
        string ID = row.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString();
        DataRow drDtata = Handler.GetRowInfo(ID);
        string isMark = drData["is_mark"].ToString();
        string mark = "";
        if (drData != null)
        {
           if (isMark == "False" || isMark == "false")
           {
               mark = "yes";
           }
           else
           {
               mark = "no";
           }
        }
        row.Cells[4].Value = mark;
        dgvMarket.Refresh();
   }
}
```

I'm sure row.Cells[4].Value had changed to mark's value, but it didn't show on UI
After I run the code, it only show datagridview with DataView dvMarket value.
And row.Cells[4] shows null.
(I'm not allowed to add new column in database)
How could I solved it?
thank you all.

Comment: Are you modifying an unbound column or are you making changes to column in the data source? Are you able to access the `DataTable` that `DataView` is created from or create a new `DataTable` from the `DataView`? You can add a column to that `DataTable`, modify the data it contains and then bind to that, so there's no messing with unbound columns.

Comment: I didn't make change to column in the data source. I bind the data source first, then try to change cell value of datagridview. And it doen's work

Comment: That's not what I was asking. You're making changes to data in the grid. I know that. Is the column(s) you're changing bound to the data source or unbound? My point is that, if the column(s) is bound then you absolutely SHOULD be making the change to the data source directly. If it's not bound then you could modify the data source so it is.

Comment: Oh, I understood your meaning. The data I would like to change unbound the data. That's the reason why I can't modify th data. Thank you so much！

Comment: I'm afraid that there's too much unknown in your code for us to diagnose the issue. In general, if you set a cell value in an unbound column then it will display in that cell. If it's not for you then it's something specific to your code but we can't run your code so we can't reproduce the issue. You need to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. If that requires creating new test project to isolate the issue then that's what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll read the article and updateit. Mayble I should rebuilt my project. And also I need to understand more about it.